# ¿Como puedo ejecutar codigo de javacript o python desde linea de comando en NeoVim?

Tags: linux, terminal

Cordial saludo mis estimados.

Como puedo ejecutar mi código en la terminal de NeoVim?, siempre tengo que abrir otra terminal par ejecutarlos, me gustaría ejecutarlo en el propio terminal del mismo proyecto, ":" mediante ese medio.

Me han cerrado la pregunta y descalificado injustamente, vuelvo a colocarla, fui lo más claro, me dan descalcificación como si mi pregunta estuviera mala.

Comment: No vuelvas a repetir la misma pregunta; será cerrada igual que la otra.

Comment: NeoVim no es un editor? Es como que quisieramos ejecutar código con el notepad.

Comment: No se ejecuta de la misma manera, lo que sucede es que en VS code y en atom.io hay plug-ins de "script" para ejecutar el plug-in en el mismo proyecto, pero el problema es que no se los comando para ejecutarlos como si fuesen en terminal, lo único que se es ejecutarlo con el comando de Python, pero luego me toca navegar con CD, luego hacer LS en la carpeta, y tabear hasta encontar el archivo , todo eso lo que dije es en la terminal. y eso es una perdida de tiempo, por eso necesito a alguien que me responda que use NeoVim, y que sepa bash, porque todo eso se ejecutan con comando del shell bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pregunte en reddit como se ejecutaban, al parecer había que agregarle un signo de admiración al principio del comando, es decir, para javascript `:!node + el script` y para Python es `:!python + el archivo`.

https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/nxinpa/how_can_i_execute_my_scriptpython_and_nodejs_in/ aqui donde hice la consulta. espero que les sirva.